# Find and return array positions of multiple values efficiently in minimal runs

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, arraylist

Find and return array positions of multiple values in a minimal runs

```
function getAllIndexes(arr, val) {
    var indexes = [], i = -1;
    while ((i = arr.indexOf(val, i+1)) != -1){
        indexes.push(i);
    }
    return indexes;
}

var Cars = ["Nano", "Volvo", "BMW", "Nano", "VW", "Nano"];

var indexes = getAllIndexes(Cars, "Nano");

//will return 0 3 5
```

How do I search for multiple items and return the positions faster and efficiently in a less time

```
var indexes = getAllIndexes(Cars, ["Nano","BMW"]);

//should return 0 2 3 5 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a different approach, because you have mor than one value to look for.

You could map the indices for matching items or take `-1` for unfound items for a later filtering run.

```js
const
    getAllIndices = (array, needles) => array
        .map((v, i) => needles.includes(v) ? i : -1)
        .filter(i => i + 1);

var cars = ["Nano", "Volvo", "BMW", "Nano", "VW", "Nano"],
    indices = getAllIndices(cars, ["Nano", "BMW"]);

console.log(indices);
```

ES5

```js
function getAllIndices(array, needles) {
    return array
        .map(function (v, i) { return needles.indexOf(v) + 1 ? i : -1; })
        .filter(function (i) { return i + 1; });
}

var cars = ["Nano", "Volvo", "BMW", "Nano", "VW", "Nano"],
    indices = getAllIndices(cars, ["Nano", "BMW"]);

console.log(indices);
```

Comment: Is it possible to use without => operator. I am actually looking for similar using Apps script

Comment: includes isnt supported in Google Apps script